# How to use ROWSPAN while grouping cells with TBODY?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using JQuery to toggle slideDown and slideUp for a section of rows in my table. To group these rows I am using tbody. Tbody is the only way of grouping that has worked for me so far. Unfortunately wrapping these rows in a tbody has made it so that rowspan is not affecting these rows anymore and has adversely affected the layout of my table. Is there any way to use both rowspan and tbody together or perhaps a different method of spanning/grouping rows?

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('.parent').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }else{
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
     }    
    });   
   $('.child').hide();
});
```

Table (within php)

```
echo '<table border="1" style="width: 330px;">';

echo '<tr style="width: 330px;">';
echo '<td colspan="3"><h1>'.highlight($search,$name).'</h1></td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr style="width: 100px; vertical-align: top;">';     
if($pic=='true'){
    if(empty($filename)){
        echo '<td rowspan="7" style="width: 100px; height: 130px;">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 130px; overflow: hidden;">
        <img src="documents/hr_contacts/nophoto.jpg" alt="'.$name.'" height="100%" style="margin-left: -18px; margin-top: -1px;">
        </div>
        </td>';
    }else{
        if($width/$height<.769){
               echo '<td rowspan="7" style="width: 100px; height: 130px;">
               <div style="width: 100px; height: 130px; overflow: hidden;">
               <img src="documents/'.$tablename.'/'.$filename.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="100%"/>
                           </div>
               </td>';
            }else{
            echo '<td rowspan="7" style="width: 100px; height: 130px;">
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 130px; overflow: hidden;">
            <img src="documents/'.$tablename.'/'.$filename.'" alt="'.$name.'" height="100%" style="margin-left: -'.((((130/$height)*$width)-100)/2).'px;"/>
            </div>
            </td>';
        }
    }
}

echo '<td style="width: 90px;">Phone: </td>';
echo '<td style="width: 140px;">'.highlight($search,$phone).'</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr style="width: 230px;">';
echo '<td style="width: 90px;">Email: </td>';
echo '<td style="width: 140px;"><a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.highlight($search,$email).'</a></td>';
echo '</tr>';

   echo '<tbody class="parent">';       
echo '<tr style="width: 230px;">';
echo '<td colspan="2"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Personal Contact Info</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody>';


echo '<tbody id="test" class="child">';
if(!empty($cell)){
    echo '<tr style="width: 230px;">';
    echo '<td style="width: 90px;">Cell Phone: </td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 140px;">'.highlight($search,$cell).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
}

if(!empty($homePhone)){
    echo '<tr style="width: 230px;">';
    echo '<td style="width: 90px;">Home Phone: </td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 140px;">'.highlight($search,$homePhone).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

if(!empty($perEmail)){
    echo '<tr style="width: 230px;">';
    echo '<td style="width: 90px;">Personal Email: </td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 140px;"><a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.highlight($search,$perEmail).'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

if(!empty($address)){
     echo '<tr style="width: 230px;">';
    echo '<td style="width: 90px;">Address: </td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 140px;">'.highlight($search,$address).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
echo '</tbody>';

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into issues and you're using jQuery it might be simpler to use CSS classes to "group" your rows instead of multiple tbody tags - then you can access those groups via jQuery selectors.

```
$('.myRowClass').slideUp();
```

Comment: That works but ideally I would like all the rows to slide together as one section. This method cause each row to slide individually